# How to count the columns of a <td> showing the total at the end

Tags: angular

I'm making a list of calls and I need to count how many attendance absences and justification each student has, but I can not. Someone could give a light.

I'm lost in this part.

```
<!-- I need count the ATTENDANCE -->
<td style="text-align: center">{{totalPresente}}</td> 
<!-- I need count the absences -->
<td style="text-align: center">00</td>
```

->>>>>>>> [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzbaez) <<<<<<<<<-

Comment: Where is your angular code and how you are counting>?

Comment: @Coding https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzbaez

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list you should use `*ngFor` to iterate over the list of data.
https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's the best solution for you but you could try using
[@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) directive to grab your table reference and then do some JavaScript e.g.:

HTML

```
<table #yourTableHashId></table>
```

TypeScript

```
@ViewChild('yourTableHashId', { read: ElementRef }) tableRef: ElementRef;

private countTdElements(): void {
    const numberOfTdElements = this.tableRef.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('td').length;
}
```